# How can I define build path in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte-3

How can I set deployment path in Svelte?
I would like to use it on the webserver in different path like

```
https://example.com/somewhere-else/index.html
```

But now right after i run **npm build**, I must use it like:

```
https://example.com/index.html
```

It must be something in the **rollup.config.js** but I cannot find it out.

Comment: Are you using Sapper?

Comment: No, just a Svelte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you are using the standard svelte template?

https://github.com/sveltejs/template

The bundles it creates are not restricted to a specific path.  You just need to put them in the appropriate path and update the link and script tags in the index.html file appropriately:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'><!-- change this -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'><!-- change this -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'><!-- change this -->

    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script><!-- change this -->
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this answer your question, or is your problem more complicated?

Comment: Actually yes, it solves the problem. Thank you for it :)